# X-Drupal-Cache http header

Tags: caching

Examining for http headers, I mentioned the header "X-Drupal-Cache HIT".
I use varnish reverse proxy.

Is it necessary for this header to appear? Can I make it be ommited? If yes, how? Would that have negative implications?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To change drupal http-header information check out [drupal_set_header()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_set_header/6) (D6) or 
[drupal_add_http_header()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_add_http_header/7) (D7).

Looking at the documentation for [_drupal_bootstrap_page_cache](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--bootstrap.inc/function/_drupal_bootstrap_page_cache/7), it seems the header shows 'HIT' if the page is displayed from cache, and 'MISS' in the case it is not.

Check out [Set X-Drupal-Cache header during page_cache_fastpath](http://drupal.org/node/897852) and [Implement better cache headers for reverse proxies](http://drupal.org/node/147310) for more information about the X-Drupal-Cache header. It seems to be a Drupal 7 or Pressflow only thing.

Comment: I think there is no specific info about at these links.